# Access the downloaded content with wget for responses with http code different than 200 OK

Tags: wget

I cannot find a switch in wget which would allow me to see the body of the response if the server returns a status other than 200 OK.

For example

```
wget 'http://stackoverflow.com/xxx'
```

will result in

```
--2012-02-08 16:38:32--  http://stackoverflow.com/xxx
Resolving stackoverflow.com... 64.34.119.12
Connecting to stackoverflow.com|64.34.119.12|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-02-08 16:38:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Is it possible access the html document which stackoverflow returns for 404 error?

I know curl would do it, the question is how to do it with wget.

Thanks

Tymek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` can't do this, but this should work:

```
curl -R -O http://stackoverflow.com/xxx
```

Also see https://superuser.com/questions/253826/how-to-use-wget-to-download-http-error-pages

Comment: I am really sorry I did not see that. But don't be pissed, I was just trying to help! It just does not work with wget...